# Trying to figure out how to make the canvas smaller for python turtle graphics but it is not working correctly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

def screen():
    screen = turtle.getscreen()
screen()   
def w():
    w = screen.screensize()
w()    
def h():
    h = screen.screensize()
h()    
turtle.setworldcoordinates() = -w//2, -h//2, w//2, h//2
```

So I am trying to be able to get the canvas to appear smaller; for some reason it is not working correctly and I am getting "can't assign to function call". I looked up the error and my functions seem fine..

any input would be helpful.

Comment: solved. Just use turtle.setworldcoordinates(100,-100,100,100)

Comment: You should accept the answer from [@Nobozarb_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12102753/nobozarb) which states that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `turtle.setworldcoordinates(-w//2, -h//2, w//2, h//2)`. What you are doing is setting the function equal to `-w//2, -h//2, w//2, h//2` rather than passing those values as parameters.